# Simulating an event to wake my Mac

Tags: sleep-wake, unix, hacking, wake-on-lan

Events like EC.cause/GIGE/LIDO/OHC/PWRB/RTC/USB# can wake up a Mac. Is there a way to programatically simulate either of these ?

WOL is out of the question as my machine doesn't support WOL on WiFi. So I am trying to find another way to wake my Mac.

Comment: Do you mean how to wake up the Mac based on time?

Comment: @Tyson No. I am trying it wake it up whenever I like. My plan is that since my Mac is receiving UDP packets on port 9 though it wont wake up because of that, I can use them to trigger one of the above events to wake up my Mac.